# Exercise on the first and second derivative of a square summable function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let be $\psi \in L^2[0,2\pi]$, that is the set of the square summable function on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Then suppose that the second derivative of that function $\psi\;''\in L^2[0,2\pi]$. It is true that also $\psi\;' \in L^2[0,2\pi]$? How can I demonstrate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second derivative exists, then $\psi'$ is continuous at a compact set (namely $[0,2\pi]$), and hence, bounded. Say that $|\psi'(x)|\le M$

Then
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|\psi'(t)|^2dt\le 2\pi M^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Another (needlessly complicated) way to see this is that the map $L^2[0,2\pi] \rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{C})$ which sends a function to its sequence of Fourier coefficients is an isomorphism. The fourier coefficients of a differentiable function $f$ satisfy (as can be checked using integration by parts)
$$
\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{in}\widehat{f'}(n),
$$
so we get in our case that
$$
\widehat{f'}(n) = \frac{1}{in}\widehat{f''}(n).
$$
so obviously $\widehat{f'}(n)$ form an $\ell^2$ sequence.